# Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error

Tags: web, mamp, htdocs, mamp-pro

I just bought a new MacBook and, after reinstalling MAMP, I moved the folder containing my site located in htdocs in the "new" htdocs and now no longer works (Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error). can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

dont worry, i got a problem like this error page "Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error" after  uploaded my local joomla design and it's database to live server. i have been trying to search the solution through internet. but some solution may help you and they were.

solution ONE:

go to your folder files search configuration.php then click to edit.

```
public $host = 'localhost';    --> change the localhost to your_localhost
public $user = 'root';         --> change the root to your_database_user
public $password = '12312';    --> change the 12312 to your_database_password
public $db = '_jos';           --? change the _jos to your_database_name
```

after your confirm the changes.
find the lines 57 and 58 to change paths and change to your_actual_paths

```
public $log_path = 'C:\wamp\www\east-horizon2\logs';
public $tmp_path =  'C:\wamp\www\east-horizon2\tmp'; --> change to 
  'home/easthori/public_html/east-horizon2/tmp';
```

solution TWO:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';      --> change to 'mysql';
```

i am wishing this solution will help you